# Spring Gateway how to route deep SPA links

Tags: angular, spring, gateway

I have an Angular application that is routed from a Spring Gateway. The root route works correctly but when you deep into nested routes it returns status not found. On [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml) and this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@nithin.biliya/deploying-angular-application-on-tomcat-server-fixing-deep-linking-issue-577565fe303d) say that you must rewrite any not found route to /index.html but I not found any reference in Spring Cloud Gateway docs for how to do configure this.

**application.yml**

```yaml
      - id: teams-frontend
        uri: lb://teams-frontend
        predicates:
          - Path=/teams,/teams/**
        filters:
          - StripPrefix=1
#         - RewritePath=/.*, /index.html  ## This breaks existing link resources such as the scripts linked on the index.html
```

How can angular app fallback to index.html when it is not found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed a [custom filter](https://gist.github.com/Vrael/67440baf190289eed965813475370bc1). If the request contains a header "Accept: text/html" then the request path is overwritten with /index.html

```yml
- id: teams-frontend
    uri: lb://teams-frontend
    predicates:
      - Path=/teams,/teams/**
    filters:
      - StripPrefix=1
      - SPA
```